# Integrating MongoDB's ObjectId into my framework

Tags: mongodb, frameworks

I'm writing a JavaScript framework that uses MongoDB as its database driver. MongoDB isn't the only driver, and the framework is not specifically targeted at working only with MongoDB. The purpose of the driver within the framework is to translate framework database calls to (in this case) MongoDB driver calls.

So far, so good. Problems start arising when I interact with _id fields, which use ObjectIds for both the primary key and for referencing other collections.

The main problem I'm facing at the moment is that if I use a list of ids in say, a select DOM element in my frontend, I have to convert the ObjectIDs to strings. But when I save a document that refers to another collection's document in one of its fields, I need to convert the string back to an ObjectID.

This is not a big thing to implement in my driver (look for values of type String whose key ends with _id) but it really starts getting nasty with embedded documents, or with an array field that contains a list of ObjectIds. Performing normal .includes or .filter operations on that array, within the framework, isn't possible unless I .map the array to strings. And since documents can be embedded endlessly, I see it only becoming a bigger mess as I develop more complex applications.

One thing I've thought about is abandoning the use of the native _id mechanism of MongoDB and implementing my own unique field for documents, but that seems to me both wasteful and not really high performance.

Is there a good way around this?

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue. We ended up using UUID strings instead, it was a lot easier. Though, with the Node.js driver we used converted ObjectIDs to strings for us, it was going back from the frontend to the back we needed a little snippet:

> Disclaimer: This is from memory, not exact

```
function someRequest(id, ...)
try {
  var oid = new ObjectID(id);
  if (!oid.isValid()) {
    throw new Error("Not an object ID");
  }
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
  var oid = id;
}
```

But worked even better was just generating UUID strings for IDs, we never had performance issues with ~100 concurrent users.

Comment: Which uuid version did you use? Aside from performance, did you ever have any issues with more advanced features like sharding?

Comment: Also, is there any particular merit in using uuids (say v4) instead of something like crypto.randomBytes(16).toString("hex")? I'd like to avoid unnecessary dependencies unless I have to, and crypto is built in into node.